# GreenDAO: generate DAO class from existing entity cause issue with relation

Tags: java, android, sqlite, greendao

All of my entities where in a .jar because I need to use them in API for a webapp and Android application.

After research, I saw greenDAO can generate only DAO class for my entity, I just have to use `setSkipGeneration(true)`

This work fine, but, I tried to test with 2 entities with one-to-many relation.
The problem is:

My entity A have a reference to entity B, so I put this relation in my DAOGenerator with `addToOne` method. But, greenDAO generator generate this method on my EntityDAO :

```
@Override
protected void attachEntity(MyEntity entity) {
    super.attachEntity(entity);
    entity.__setDaoSession(daoSession);
}
```

However, `entity.__setDaoSession(daoSession)` is impossible, because my entity need to have a `DaoSession` object in its class, but it's impossible like I said at the beginning.

I thought I was doing the right thing when I use `setSkipGeneration(true)` but I probably forget something, do you have the answer to my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You asked generator to create the convinience methods for your entity to deal with relationship,  `addToOne`. Those methods need DB access which is done through `DaoSession`. If for some reason you can not afford `DaoSession` in the class, just do not ask for relationship methods.